# Why is the shalshelet trope (cantillation) note always at the beginning of the verse and always followed by a psik?

Tags: torah-reading, trop-cantillation

The shalshelet trope note appears in 4 places in the Torah:

Breishit 19:16, Bresihit 24:12, Breishit 39:8, and Vayikra 8:23.

In all cases the note is on the 1st word of its verse and is followed by a *psik*. I understand that part of the trope notes function is grammatical. I'm assuming that there is a grammatical reason that requires *shalshalet* to be on the 1st word and must be followed by a psik. Why?

Comment: Did you check instances on shalshelet in the other 16 books? Why limit just to Torah?

Comment: see my answer on this, related question.
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/why-does-moshe-have-a-shalshelet

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/shalsheles-trop?lq=1#comment11167_4224 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/shalsheles-trop?lq=1#comment11168_4224 In short, if it wasn't the first word it would become a Segol, and the Psik is there to indicate it's the pausal kind of Shalshelet (there is also a connective kind in Taamei Emet).

Comment: @joshwaxman FYI I _frequently_ refer people to that answer of yours.